# importing modules in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I created a small module and I want to use it in my program. I’m able to import it in the program and use it. However, I’m not able to import it in ghci. This is causing a lot of problems as I’m not able to test things interactively which I’d like to.

Essentially, I’m creating Geometry.hs from here (http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#making-our-own-modules) and trying to import it in my program which works. If I do the same thing in ghci, it doesn’t. I run ghci from the same directory where Geometry.hs is present.

This is my program.

```
import Geometry
main = putStrLn $ show $ Geometry.sphereVolume 1
```

I try to execute the same lines in ghci and get this error -

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Geometry'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Comment: First of all, `putStrLn . show` is the same as `print`.  Are you typing import into GHCi directly using `import Geometry`?  The `:load` (or just `:l`) command is usually used to load local source files.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. That indeed was the solution to my problem.

Comment: @shashydhar: More details can be found at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope.

Comment: @Zeta - I think the link has changed to [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#what-s-really-in-scope-at-the-prompt](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#what-s-really-in-scope-at-the-prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that we keep our answered questions ratio high on the Haskell tag, the solution was to use the `:load` or `:l` directives in GHCi to load the source file in the current directory.  As [@Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129630/importing-modules-in-haskell#comment37230437_24129630) notes, the documentation with more details can be found at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope